# How to delete helm release by namespace and older than 10 days

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to delete releases older than 10 days, but some namespace shouldn't be touched (ex: monitoring)
In helm2 i did it with awk, but in helm3 they changed date type so it's not working.
Is there any way to do that?

Comment: did try to achieve your task and it didn't works?

Comment: i tried to use jq. It is too not working.

Answer (score 1):

Let me show you how I've resolved a similar issue. In our flow, we have an automatic rollout of helm releases for every feature branch, and we decided to implement an automatic cleanup process for deleting old feature releases in the development flow.

The current implementation requires jq as a dependency.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

echo "Staring delete-old-helm-release.sh ..."

helm_release_name=${1:-$HELM_RELEASE_NAME}
k8s_namespace=${2:-$KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE}

# Get helm release date, take updated field and remove UTC from string
helm_release_updated=$(helm list --filter "${helm_release_name}" -n "${k8s_namespace}" -o json \
  | jq --raw-output ".[0].updated" \
  | sed s/"UTC"// \
)

if [[ "$helm_release_name" == null ]]; then
  echo "Helm release: ${helm_release_name} in namespace: ${k8s_namespace} not found"
  echo "Exit from delete-old-helm-release.sh ..."
  exit 1
fi

# Convert date string to timestamp, get current timestamp and calculate time delta
helm_release_date_timestamp=$(date --utc --date="${helm_release_updated}" +"+%s")
current_date_timestamp=$(date --utc +"+%s")
time_difference=$((current_date_timestamp - helm_release_date_timestamp))

# 86400 means 24 hours (60*60*24) in seconds
if [[ (( $time_difference -gt 86400 )) ]]; then
  echo "Detected old release: ${helm_release_name} in namespace: ${k8s_namespace}"
  echo "Difference is more than 24hr: $((time_difference/60/60))hr"
  echo "Deliting it ..."
  helm delete "${helm_release_name}" -n "${k8s_namespace}" --purge
  echo "Done"
else
  echo "Detected fresh release"
  echo "Current time difference is less than 24hr: $((time_difference/60/60))hr"
  echo "Skipping ..."
fi

exit 0
```

It's tested with helm 3.2.4 and I think it should work with all helm 3.x.x until they changed date format.

BTW, please update your issue description so it will be more clear and have bigger priority in search engines :)

Please let me know is it helps,
Good luck,
Oleg

Comment: Thanks dude. You helped me a lot